# How does Prometheus client libraries behave when Prometheus is down?

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus. According to what I have read and tried so far, Prometheus client libraries expose collected metrics over HTTP and Prometheus reads (scrapes) that periodically.

Until Prometheus scrapes metrics, client libraries must be storing collected metrics in memory. So what happens if Prometheus server goes down?

1. Will the client library keep collecting data?
2. Is there any limits to stop collecting?
3. Or does that drop oldest data?
4. How does it avoid going OOM?

Please correct me if I have assumed anything wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prometheus client libraries don't store individual events, they update metrics. So it'll keep updating those metrics and there's no risk of OOM.

See https://www.robustperception.io/memory-usage-of-prometheus-client-libraries for more information.

Comment: Thank you Brian. This brought me to another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485068/cant-i-push-raw-request-data-to-prometheus