# Can't I push raw request data to Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I have a requirement to count API calls grouped by certain headers. For example, I want to find out how many API calls had `headerX=valueY`.

For that, I want to publish a metric like this (please ignore the naming convention) so that I can query later.

`http_request{HeaderX=valueR, HeaderY=valueM, etc...}`

If that's possible to do with Prometheus, please help me with it.

Comment: That's possible but might create a lot of additional series, depending on how many possible values there are for HeaderX and HeaderY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tkausl observed, it is possible but not recommended. You don't say which specific client (i.e. Java, Go, Python etc.) you're using, so here's a Java example":

```
static final Counter httpRequests = Counter.build()
    .name("http_requests_total")
    .help("Total number of requests by path and header values.")
    .labelNames("path", "content_type", "user_agent")
    .register();
```

And then in your request handler/interceptor:

```
httpRequests.labels(requestPath, contentType, userAgent).inc();
```

The reason this not recommended is that if your headers can have an infinite number of values (and they can, since you can make a `curl` request with whatever random header values you please) then you can end up with an infinite number of time series. E.g.

```
http_requests_total{path="/",content_type="text/plain",user_agent="curl 1.0"} 5
http_requests_total{path="/",content_type="text/plain",user_agent="curl 1.0-whatever"} 1
http_requests_total{path="/",content_type="text/plain",user_agent="curl 1.0-the"} 1
http_requests_total{path="/",content_type="text/plain",user_agent="curl 1.0-client"} 1
http_requests_total{path="/",content_type="text/plain",user_agent="curl 1.0-wants"} 1
```

Now multiply that for each label (say you have 10 API endpoints, 10 different content types and 100 different user agents, you've got yourself 10k metrics.

So if you're really interested in a couple of possible headers and a handful of possible values (say JSON, XML and text; and Chrome, Firefox and IE), then record those specific values (say `"application/json"`) or use a regex to match for `".*Chrome.*"` and then record `"Chrome"` as the label value. And for any header value that doesn't match, you can use `"other"` or whatever specific value you want. That way your clients can't blow up your Prometheus. (The client library can likely manage the multiple values much longer than Prometheus, which needs to keep a timeseries for each value, even if it's forever stuck at 1.)