# How long metrics endpoint retain data for Prometheus .net core client application?

Tags: prometheus

I have created a metrics endpoint for a .net core application using KestrelMetricServer.

```
var metricServer = new KestrelMetricServer(1234);
metricServer.Start();
```

What is the default metrics data storage policy here and how can we override this?
What if the endpoint data are not scraped?
How long it will be stored in application memory?

I could not find any documentation about this for the .net core client.

Comment: Kestrel AFAIK is http server used in prometheus client for .net. It shouldn't store anything. Data is stored by prometheus.

Comment: But the application actually keep the data metrics for sometime for the metrics endpoint which is consumed by the Prometheus. I need to know how long it will be kept into the memory for the endpoint and how can we configure it for dot net core application.

Comment: After reading the answer for this thread it seems to me that client only update the matrics, so no need to worry about for the out of memory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477833/1785657

Comment: "But the application actually keep the data metrics for sometime" - no it doesn't. It obviously store metric values, but no history. Every request to "/metric" initiates new generation of metrics in text format, and after it they are dropped from the memory. Unless you specify custom metrics collector, that will store something, but it's whole another story.

Comment: @markalex Thanks for your response. I am a bit confused if it does not contain the time level data then how the chart is generated then. For example, for a certain time, RPS is 100 and for the next second it is 50, then how the Prometheus server will know at which time was the count?

Comment: Prometheus marks time when it scraped data from your exporter.

Comment: Thanks, here I got a good explanation of how it works.
 https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work/